# PHP return false if certain word appears in $_POST[xxx]

Tags: php

I have a coming soon form at a website where user fills out an email form and it will be emailed to me. However, a spammer has hit the site and is spamming the form with goatse and so on. IP ban isn't helping so I need to stop the form sending it if it contains goatse or something. Here's the mailer.

```
<?php
$SPOSTI =$_POST[sposti];


if ($SPOSTI=="")
{
    return false;
}

if ($SPOSTI=="goatse.fr")
{
    return false;
}
if ($SPOSTI=="http://www.goatse.info/hello.jpg")
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    $to = "xxx@gmail.com";
    $subject = "xxx";
    $message = "$_POST[sposti] haluaa tiedon kun kotisivut.name avautuu.
    $_POST[ip]";
    $from = "$_POST[sposti]";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
    ?>
```

Is there someway to block it from executing the code if the email contains a certain word (goatse in this case)

Comment: Er, among other things - `if($SPOSTI == ' ') { return "You're uberboned.'; }`

Comment: What? That only stops the form from sending if its empty?

Comment: You're approaching the problem the wrong way. Wait until you start getting "replica watches", "cialis" and such... Blacklisting words, IPs, urls, only gets you so far and can result in false positives which require additional measures. Sorry to say there is no silver bullet for this very common problem...

Comment: I know this guy, and he stops at goatse. Believe me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `exit` or `die` instead of `return false` which works inside functions/methods:

```
if ( $SPOSTI =="" || strpos('goatse', $SPOSTI) !== FALSE)
{
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Okay, does this work if goatse is includes like this: wdwijdgoatseidw`?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen It does, `strpos()` search for any string inside another.

Comment: That's a nice and simple approach, however, you only check 'sposti' from $_POST. What if the attacker sends this string in 'ip' for example, which is used in the email as well?

Answer (score 0):

`strpos()` will let you find a substring, but I really recommend a captcha security system as the attacker could simply switch to another annoying word.

Goatse's arn't your problem here, it's the security.

Comment: I hate captcha. And so do other people.

Comment: Well it's the only way to filter real humans from robots. Otherwise you rely on the fact everyone on internet likes you, which is apparently not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stristr` http://php.net/manual/de/function.stristr.php to achive this. I would recommend to using a captcha, since it is more efficient. A popular solution is reCaptcha: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php Another, weaker possibility is to add a security question to your form, for instance "What is five plus five in numbers?".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function is_spam($array, $block_pattern){
    $block = false;
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if(preg_match('/.*' . $block_pattern . '.*/', $k) ||
           preg_match('/.*' . $block_pattern . '.*/', $v)){
            $block = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $block;
}

Usage: is_spam($_POST, 'goatse');
Returns: true if 'goatse' is found in $_POST
```

The function will search all keys and values of `$array` for the `$block_pattern` string and will return `true` if the pattern is found.

Comment: Upvoted, I like your approach with a function and Usage/Returns information. Very vivid.